# Flex Spark DataGrid Cell Click?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex-spark

I am searching for something like CellClick event on Spark DataGrid, or something alike.

- Is there something like this in Flex 4.5, and how to get the data from the clicked cell ?

Comment: Which component are you using?

Comment: ups. didnt mention it on the question itself. sorry. i just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a review of the ASDocs, it looks like you want to use the [gridClick](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#event%3agridClick) event.

It has a direct hook to the [itemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/GridEvent.html) if that's what you're after.